# Solution to the Massive Laplacian Operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Let $\phi(x,y)$ be the solution of the PDE: $$(-\Delta + m)\phi(x,y) = \delta(x-y)$$ where $m > 0$ and $\Delta$ is the usual $d$-dimensional Laplace operator. I've read that the solution of this equation can be written as: $$\phi(x,y) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d}}\int e^{-ik(x-y)}(k^{2}+m^{2})^{-1}dk $$
but I'm having trouble proving it. The obvious way is to use Fourier transforms but I didn't get too far. Can you help me, please?

Comment: What happened when you tried to take the Fourier transform?

Comment: Using Fourier transform on both sides, the left hand side becomes $\int (-k^{2}+m)e^{ikx}\phi(x,y)dk$ and the right hand side becomes $\int e^{-ik(x-y)}dk$?